# ORACLE 12.2 - Major Loss in Performance with Local Indexes in "highly" Partitioned Model

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, query-optimization, partitioning

**Problem**

- I was setting up a database partitioned by list and sub partitioned by list also and everything was fine until I scaled up my partition's number.
- A simple query that ran in milliseconds goes for 1 minute and 49 seconds now (no extra data in database, only more partitions)

**My setup**

- 54 tables
- 10k partitions and 1 sub partition per table (for now)
- an average of 10 indexes per table

DDL setup:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13V8Tcv5kTl6QuPqTya6kqImbZlWGd1jk

...

**Use Case**

My tests were two instructions running on an near empty database

1 - one simple select always going for the partition and sub partition key

2 - one delete with partition and sub partition

Test case 1 - trace and execution:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19eWUoxckaIPCyFU0jorK8wrSf-HgjhWA

**Troubleshooting**

- removed all indexes and the problem was "solved"
- index range scan took almost 100% of the execution time
- same setup, but with 1.6k partitions per table is ok

**Enemy number one (extracted from the trace)**

>

```
SQL ID: 9b4m3fr3vf9kn Plan Hash: 2436900644

select obj#, dataobj#, subpart#, hiboundlen, hiboundval, flags, ts#, file#, 
  block#, pctfree$, initrans, maxtrans, analyzetime, samplesize, rowcnt, 
  blevel, leafcnt, distkey, lblkkey, dblkkey, clufac, spare2, 
  length(bhiboundval), bhiboundval 
from
 indsubpart$ where pobj# = :1 order by subpart#


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse       23      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute 230000     19.13      20.91          0          0          0           0
Fetch   460000     25.59      27.83       3357    1380000          0      230000
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total   690023     44.73      48.75       3357    1380000          0      230000

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Misses in library cache during execute: 1
Optimizer mode: CHOOSE
Parsing user id: USERNAME   (recursive depth: 1)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         1          1          1  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID INDSUBPART$ (cr=5 pr=4 pw=0 time=1813 us starts=1 cost=4 size=69 card=1)
         1          1          1   INDEX RANGE SCAN I_INDSUBPART_POBJSUBPART$ (cr=4 pr=3 pw=0 time=1317 us starts=1 cost=3 size=0 card=1)(object id 815)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  PGA memory operation                            2        0.00          0.00
  cell single block physical read              3357        0.01          1.68
  latch: shared pool                              1        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

**Doubts**
- I am far from the logical limits: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032, but still have a big cut in performance, am I doing something wrong on my DDL or is it the setup simply oversized?

**Note**
- Maybe the setup is incorrect, but the first question is: should it be breaking at this point?

Thank you